# chrome.tabs.getCurrent returns undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my first extension which requires me getting the id of my current tab. I've got the code below in a script that is set in the manifest as background. The issue is that it only returns undefined. Not sure what to do next. Thanks for any help!

```
function oneFunction() {

    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(mytab){

            console.log(mytab);

    })

}

var t=setInterval(oneFunction,1000);
```

Comment: See the documentation: getCurrent is for a different purpose. You need query({active: true, currentWindow:true}, callback)

Comment: [How can I get the current tab URL for chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/17826527)

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow:true}, function(tabs)
{

});
```

And also know that `tabs` is an array containing the tabs matching your query info. In this case the array will have length 1, so you must use it as `tabs[0]`